# Route AngularJS app without changing URI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-4

I am trying to create an Angular API which should be able to be integrated on any webpage. I have a frontApp using AngularJS and a backend which uses Laravel 4.

The problem is that my routing look like this at the moment :

```
angular.module('FrontApp').config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        })
        .when('/register', {
            templateUrl: 'views/register.html',
            controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
        })
        .when('/members', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        })
        .when('/apinotfound', {
            templateUrl: 'views/api.html'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
}]);
```

But since my App will be integrated on a webpage whose URI can not changed, I can not use this routing system. I was wondering if a trick would be possible, to keep those routes in a variable maybe, and then route my App without changing the URI of the page?

Comment: check out the angular-ui router library. it will allow you to nest views as states within a single view/URI

Comment: Thanks, it seems possible to specify the same URI for all the states of my application with this library. I am going to give it a try